# How do you hide a div using localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I been playing with ***windows.localStorage*** and couldn't figure out how to save variable. So far I know how to store **text** but how do you keep something being **True**
Anyway I have this code demo here:

```
[HideForever](https://jsfiddle.net/PeterzH/rxawdxkw/)
```

, and feel free to use jQuery if you have to
Thanks for the help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Values you save in [localStorage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage/setItem) are Strings only.

You can't use any other types (not boolean, not objects).

You can use the strings `'0'/'1'` (and later on check if the value `== '0'` or `== '1'`).

Comment: If I store one var as **0** init and onclick change it to **1**, can I use this var in the html and call if **==** then **ng-show=true**?

Comment: I'm not sure how it is related to `ng-show=true`, but you can try.